# Linux command to find directories of n days old

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I am using the command "find /path/* -type d -ctime +5" to find directories which are 5 days old. This command lists the directory and all its sub-directories. But I want to stop at the first matched directory.

For the following directory structure:
/temp/a/b/c/file.txt
Let's say directories 'b' and 'c' were created 5 days ago.
The above command lists the following as the output:
/temp/a/b and /temp/a/b/c.

Instead of the above output, I want only "/temp/a/b" as the output.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62880/how-to-stop-the-find-command-after-first-match ?

Comment: Do you want to stop after the first matched directory or do you want the shortest path for every old subtree?

Answer (score 0):

You can stop searching a branch with `-prune`:

```
find /path -type d -ctime +4 -prune
```

This will print all the directories whose ctime is older than 5 days, but skip all their subdirectories.